# representation of acp individuals

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

i would like to reprensent individuals ACP in a graph with colors and label, but it doesn't work i have only color  i can't pin up labels and legend, can anyone help me please. here is my result

[image]

here is my code

```
palette = plt.get_cmap("Dark2")
# associe une couleur à chaque continent (cf ci-dessous)
couleurs = dict(zip(dt_df["Bandes"].drop_duplicates(), palette(range(7))))#9 bandes
couleurs
position = dict(zip(couleurs.keys(), range(7))) #9 bandes

#Affichage des points avec une liste de couleurs
dt_df.plot.scatter(x = "CP1", y = "CP2", c = [couleurs[p] for p in dt_df["Bandes"]])
# boucle pour afficher la légende
for cont, coul in couleurs.items():
    plt.scatter(3, position[cont] / 3 + 2.15, c = [coul], s = 20)
    plt.text(3.2, position[cont] / 3 + 2, cont)
   # plt.legend()
    plt.show() 
plt.xlabel("Dimension 1 ") 
plt.ylabel("Dimension 2")
plt.suptitle("Premier plan factoriel")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "ACP." Can you elaborate on what that is? Thanks!

Comment: acp is principal components analysis

Comment: any one can help please